# Excel multiple search/match and sum (edit: answered with SUMIFS, COUNTIFS)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for help to solve this excel problem.

Essentially I want to create a formula for cells in column F which does a multiple search on 3 criteria (on cells in columns A,B,C) and want to access the corresponding column D values where all these (multiple) matches occur, and sum this in column F. I'd also like a count of the amount of matches found to calculate the value in column F; placed alongside in column G.

e.g.

```
IF col_A_value (anywhere in whole A column) = current_col_A_value +/- 1

AND col_B_value (anywhere in whole B column) = current_col_B_value +/- 1

AND col_C_value (anywhere in whole C column) = current_col_C_value - 1

THEN (output in column F) the sum of all values from row D where this criteria is met
```

(also, as a seperate but related cell formula, output in column G) the total Count of times this occurs.

Note: the values in columns A,B,C are all integars and the +/- above means to search for any values which are either +1, 0, or -1 different in value. (i.e. this includes the value itself).

e.g. If the value in cell A1 = 10, B1 = 45, C1 = 881, then the first search criteria would look for all other rows with values of 9, 10 or 11 in column A. Then based on these rows, the second search criteria would refine the search to only those rows which also include either a 44, 45 or 46 in column B, and the third search criteria would refine the search again to only include those rows where the column C value is 880.
Next, the values in the column D cells from all of these 'filtered' rows would be summed and the result placed in the column F cell. (The count of these results rows would be put in column G. (seperate formula required))

Since these are all unique entries (think of columns A,B,C creating unique vector coordinates in space), there should be a maximum of 9 entries found and summed. A +/-1: 3 variations, B +/-1: 3 variations and C -1 only: 1 variation. In total: 3x3x1 = 9 unique rows maximum (and potentially none as a minimum, as in the below example).

(If no match is found a value of 0 is good.)

Example with A,B,C,D and E as given values, and column F values calculated (together with the count shown in col G):

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G

1   1   1   90  8   0   0
1   2   1   80  6   0   0
1   3   1   70  1   0   0
1   4   1   60  6   0   0
2   1   1   50  1   0   0
2   2   1   40  8   0   0
2   3   1   30  6   0   0
2   4   1   20  8   0   0
3   1   1   10  8   0   0
3   2   1   11  6   0   0
3   3   1   12  1   0   0
3   4   1   13  1   0   0
1   1   2   99  8   260 4
1   2   2   89  6   360 6
1   3   2   79  1   300 6
1   4   2   69  6   180 4
2   1   2   59  1   281 6
2   2   2   49  8   393 9
```

etc

To illustrate how column F values are calculated here is the working:

260 = 90+80+50+40

360 = 90+80+70+50+40+30

300 = 80+70+60+40+30+20

180 = 70+60+30+20

281 = 90+80+50+40+10+11

393 = 90+80+70+50+40+30+10+11+12

Thanks a lot for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulas should do what you desire:

```
F1: =SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"<="&A1+1,A:A,">="&A1-1,B:B,"<="&B1+1,B:B,">="&B1-1,C:C,C1-1)
G1: =COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&A1+1,A:A,">="&A1-1,B:B,"<="&B1+1,B:B,">="&B1-1,C:C,C1-1)
```

The formulas can simply be copied down as you need them...
(Still I don't know what col E is for)

Comment: Col E is not used in this formula (at the moment: sorry for including it in the example if it created any confusion). Your answer is ex btw, cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Really appreciated. Being a new user I can't upvote your answer yet though.